# Is the public road limited to the ground?

Tags: definition, public-law

this is a simple question: is the public property only limited to ground level ? 
By this I mean if I hang items by the window of my room (I live right on a street, no private under the window) is it still considered to be in my own private property or not ? In the former case, can I be incrimanted for somthing ?

Sorry if the terminology is wrong, I work in a field so foreign to law...

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking about hanging something outside your window, or hanging something inside your window that is visible to people who are passing by on the street?

Comment: I'm talking about hanging something outside of the physical building, so that it hangs over the public road

Comment: Most jurisidictions have permitting schemes for things like that (entrance stairways on urban buildings, awnings, flags, signs).  So in general, no, the property line is actually a surface that separates the space above private ground from the space above public ground (or separates the space above each of two different private plots).  Whether it is criminal to hang that thing over the property line, though, depends on what the thing is and in what jurisdiction you live.

Comment: Far too dependent on jurisdiction, details of the thing, details of the place, reason for having the thing in the place, ...

Comment: What you may be looking for is both who owns the ground under the sidewalk or street and who owns the "air rights."